# cd in a Makefile doesn't seems to be taken into account after sshfs

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sshfs, makefile

I have a Makefile with a `sshfs` command followed with a `cd` command:

```
mr: # mount-remote
        sshfs -p 5022 -o nonempty myname@myssh.serveur.fr:mnt /home/julien/myworking_path
        cd ./working_directory_mwe1/wk_subd_mwe2/
```

The first command, sshfs works like a charm and correctly mounts both endpoint. However, the cd command does not change directory. I then have to re-type it manually. It then works if I type in manually, but I want it to be done when typing the `mr` command.

I tried the following instead having in mind that it may be because I have my terminal connecting for 2 seconds while executing the `sshfs` but that did not work either. I tried to re-run `cd` every second until it works.

```
mr: # mount-remote
        sshfs -p 5022 -o nonempty myname@myssh.serveur.fr:mnt /home/julien/myworking_path
        until cd ./working_directory_mwe1/wk_subd_mwe2/ ; do sleep 1 ; done
```

Thank you for your kind help :)

EDIT: I forgot to specify that the minimal working directories I tried to `cd` is exactly the one at the endpoint, actually, I realized my aim is rather:

```
mr: # mount-remote
        sshfs -p 5022 -o nonempty myname@myssh.serveur.fr:mnt /home/julien/myworking_path
        cd /home/julien/myworking_path/some_sub_dir1/som_sub_dir2
```

Comment: Instead of `cd ./working_directory_mwe1/wk_subd_mwe2/` what happens when if you change it to `cd /home/julien/myworking_path/working_directory_mwe1/wk_subd_mwe2/`? Also, see what happens if you do this: `cd ${HOME}/myworking_path/working_directory_mwe1/wk_subd_mwe2/`. Assuming you are logging in as `julien` then `${HOME}` should be `/home/julien`.

Comment: In a Makefile, each line is run in a different shell. If you want to run something in a different directory, you need to `cd /dir && something`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I tried cd `/home/julien/myworking_path/working_directory_mwe1/wk_subd_mwe2/` instead as suggested by @Giacomo1968 but it did not succeed neither. I edited my question, I forgot a, maybe important, point

Comment: Confused by your comment. I recommended `cd /home/julien/myworking_path/working_directory_mwe1/wk_subd_mwe2/` and not `cd /home/`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, wrote too fast, comment edited. I think @user1686's answer has it right

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> However, the cd command does not change directory.

It does – but it only affects the temporary shell subprocess spawned by 'make', not the interactive shell above them.

The "current directory" is not a terminal-wide parameter – **each process has its own** current directory, and changes to it in child processes never propagate upwards (they can only be inherited down by new processes created after the change).

```
xterm
 └─ bash (interactive)
     └─ make mr
         ├─ /bin/sh -c "sshfs -p ..."
         │   └─ sshfs -p ...
         └─ /bin/sh -c "cd ..."
```

This means that nothing you do in the Makefile can directly affect the parent shell after `make` exits, and the same applies to scripts written in any other language. (Environment variables work the same way, too.)

The only way to make this work is to turn `mr` (that is, "mr" alone, no longer "make mr") into a shell **alias** or a shell **function** – both of which are executed internally to the shell.

Functions can be defined in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
mr() {
    sshfs foo:mnt ~/working_path
    cd ~/working_path/something
}
```

Note that you don't have to type the parenthesis when invoking shell functions, only when defining them. Once defined they behave like regular commands and are invoked as just `mr`. ([See also](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/basicgrammar?s%5B%5D=function#shell_function_definitions) other ways to define them.)

If the function is sufficiently short and simple (and in particular, if doesn't need to accept arguments through $1 etc.), then it can be an alias instead – aliases are able to change the current directory as well:

```
alias mr='sshfs foo:mnt ~/working_path && cd ~/working_path/something'
```

---

On top of that, regular make runs each line in a *separate* shell subprocess, so even further commands in the same Make recipe remain unaffected.

If you had instead wanted the `cd` to affect the Make recipe, you would need to either join all recipe lines into a single "logical line" using `\` continuations, like this:

```
mr:
    sshfs foo:mnt ~/myworking_path
    cd ./working_directory_mwe1/wk_subd_mwe2/ && \
        pwd && ls && echo "This happens in the new directory..."
    pwd && ls && echo "...this is back in the old one."
```

...or use the GNU Make-specific `.ONESHELL:` special target:

```
.ONESHELL:

mr:
    sshfs foo:mnt ~/myworking_path
    cd ./working_directory_mwe1/wk_subd_mwe2/
    pwd; ls; echo "This time the directory change did carry over."
```